# how to view gnuplot generated in unix server invoking from windows terminal

Tags: linux, matlab

I require to use matlab and gnuplot for my work. To do any work using matlab and gnuplot I have to log in to a machine with fedora os using ssh because the machine I am using is a windows machine. I am not getting any display on my machine when I run any of these programme. I have tried different options of set terminals, including

'set terminal windows'.

nothing worked. What shall i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that ssh X11 forwarding is enabled in your terminal client (which you did not mention), and you need an X11 program running on your windows machine - I use Xming (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)

However, I strongly advise you to use a non-graphical interface for Matlab, as it can be very slow to use over ssh/X11. You can use the textual `nodisplay` option when you run Matlab. You can maybe do the same with gnuplot (that is, save plots to disk and copy them to your local machine).